# Thymeleaf + Spring boot how to avoid creating an instance with a GET request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Learning Spring and stumbled upon a misunderstanding

There is a form with two fields "name" and "age" when sending which a User object is created and placed in a list that is then displayed on the main page

everything is fine, but in the Thymeleaf + Spring boot bundle there is a need to create an instance of the user model with each GET request, as in the example below, i.e. the object is created twice before it gets to the list and as for me it is not very good

So, how to do it (using Thymeleaf) so that the object is NOT created with every GET request?

```java
@GetMapping("/new")
    public String add(User user){ // first instantiation of User
        return "new";
    }
```

```java
@PostMapping("/new")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute User user) { // second instantiation of User
        users.add(user);
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not instantinating a `User` class. In your example it's just a parameter of a method.

It might be quite difficult to reply your question without seeing more code, but let's take a look.

You have mentioned:

> everything is fine, but in the Thymeleaf + Spring boot bundle there is
>   a need to create an instance of the user model with each GET request,
>   as in the example below, i.e. the object is created twice before it
>   gets to the list and as for me it is not very good

Actually there is no such need. You need to have such parameter just in your POST method. So You can remove it from the `add` method, then it should look like below:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public String add(){ 
    return "new";
}
```

In above example, there should be a `new.html` template file, which - I assume - is a form to add a new user in your case.

EDIT:
As this is a form, it should be binded to the object. So you need to use a Model and then add your Login object to the model:

```
@GetMapping("/new")
public String add(Model model){ 
    model.addAttribute("login", new Login());
    return "new";
}
```

Comment: in my example, the spring creates a user bean, without this parameter there will be an error

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute

Comment: Try with the code from my edited answer - I added a Model attribute, then added login to the model.

Comment: what you wrote and my code is equivalent, the problem is more clearly demonstrated in your code, new Login() called on every get request, which seems to me not very good, I want to avoid this